Unresolved External Symbol with CURL
I have been away from C++ for 10 years and the DEV environment has changed significantly !
I am trying to add the <curl/curl.h> library to my environment.  I have downloaded and installed CURL 8.7.1 and have made the following changes in Visual Studio 2022 :
Properties  >  VC++ Directories  >  Include Directories :  
C:\Users\owner\source\CURL\curl-8.7.1\curl-8.7.1\builds\libcurl-vc15-x64-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel\include

Properties  >  VC++ Directories  >  Library Directories :
C:\Users\owner\source\CURL\curl-8.7.1\curl-8.7.1\builds\libcurl-vc15-x64-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel\lib

Properties  >  Linker  >  Input  >  Additional Dependencies :
"C:\Users\owner\source\CURL\curl-8.7.1\curl-8.7.1\builds\libcurl-vc15-x64-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel\lib\libcurl_a_debug.lib"
"C:\Users\owner\source\CURL\curl-8.7.1\curl-8.7.1\builds\libcurl-vc15-x64-release-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel\lib\libcurl_a.lib"

I have tried the following VERY BASIC code (adding individual codelines until I get exceptions) ...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <curl\curl.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Submit a Request to the Data247 Service ...
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
    }
    return 0;                                                           // Return a Normal Termination Code
}

I am getting the following exceptions :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_curl_easy_init referenced in function main ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\owner\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj 1       

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\owner\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe   1       


Since you've specified the library directory you should only need the actual library name in Additional Dependencies, not the full path again.

have you looked at this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012606/c-curl-library-linker-error-but-included-the-right-libs

it appears you are linking to the static version of the library, but code thinks you are calling the dynamic version (_imp prefix indicates it should be dynamically linked). The 'static' in the library path makes me think those are static libraries.

you need to define CURL_STATICLIB see also the faq
